# help needed in editing a flash file

Tags: flash

I have never worked on flash but am trying to make some additions to the following flash: http://kcmbuild.com/

basically just want to add some more text. same as "cost consulting"  for example "hello world"

There is no .fla file..only .sfw so I used a de-compiler to make a .fla file. I thought it would be as easy as just adding "hello world" but it looks like everything is a image. the current text, "cost consulting", is in a folder called "Shape".

Can someone tell me how to go aboud achieving what I want?

I am downloading trial version of adobe flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a layer above it and try perhaps adding the text to that layer on the frame you want it to be on.

Though I'm not too sure if you are saying the entire flash is incorporated into one Shape container or just a folderset. If possible can you explain exactly what is complicating your task? Perhaps a screenshot.